# How do you contact a human behind iTunesConnect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I don't know if the iTunesConnect [Contact Us](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs) page is a fun way for Apple to troll developers or if there's a hidden path through this maze that I haven't found yet. But from what I can tell, you can't actually contact anyone using the Contact Us page. Instead, it navigates you through a tree of answers that have nothing to do with your actual question, and when you get to the end, you loop back to the beginning, but never actually contact anyone at all.

I have a question about iTunesConnect. Before I ask it here, I was wondering if there was perhaps another way to get ahold of someone at Apple?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're a registered Developer, you can just call the Apple Developer Program Support number for your country.

The direct link is: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

If you wanted to know how to navigate to this, you would just:

- Login at https://developer.apple.com
- Select Support in the main menu
- Scroll down to and select Contact Us
- Scroll down to the *Enrollment and Account* subheading
- Click on *Apple Developer Program Support*
- This will open a Contact Us form
- Above your details you'll see a link for [call us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/)

Comment: This is fantastic. I feel like as a developer, navigating a help system shouldn't be such a challenge for me. But I got caught in an infinite loop and couldn't quite find my way out.Thank you.

Comment: Great. Is it possible to email them?

Comment: Found email: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/150.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1.3.1.1.3.0.1.0.7.2